# Azure Runbook Running Sql Query: The target principal name is incorrect. Cannot generate SSPI context."

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, powershell, azure-runbook

Hi I am trying to run a SQL query on one of my databases using an Azure Runbook. My setup is listed below. When I test this, I get the error `The target principal name is incorrect. Cannot generate SSPI context."` I have looked around and have not found anything related to an Azure setup. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
$myCred = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name 'my-cred'
$userName = $myCred.UserName
$securePassword = $myCred.Password
$password = $myCred.GetNetworkCredential().Password

#Query to execute
# Invoke to Azure SQL DB
invoke-sqlcmd2 -ServerInstance $ServerName -Database $DatabaseName -Credential $SQLServerCred -Query $SqlQuery -Encrypt
```

Comment: The posted code doesn't set `$SQLServerCred` - which should be the result of `Get-AutomationPSCredential`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, looks you did not set `$SQLServerCred` before.

Try:

```
$myCred = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name 'my-cred'
$userName = $myCred.UserName
$securePassword = $myCred.Password
$SQLServerCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($userName , $securePassword)

#Query to execute
# Invoke to Azure SQL DB
invoke-sqlcmd2 -ServerInstance $ServerName -Database $DatabaseName -Credential $SQLServerCred -Query $SqlQuery -Encrypt
```